# fancyapp's addEventListener fails on load

Tags: addeventlistener

I am just trying out Fancybox 4, adding it to an old static html gallery. I have added in the head:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css" />
```

as specified, and each thumbnail image in my gallery links to a large image thusly:

```
<a href="01-Makeup.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery"><img src="01-Makeup-tb.jpg" alt="Makeup" /></a>
```

Clicking a thumbnail opens the image directly in the same window, replacing the page. In the console, the following error is shown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Function.value (fancybox.umd.js:2)
```

Apparently some other initialization is necessary, but I have no clue what is missing. Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, stumbled on same issue, just load script in footer. If you are using theme enqueue, add `true` for loading in footer.

Then it will work.

Hopefully this helps you! :)

Comment: OMG! It's that simple! Thank you, works like a charm now.

Comment: @Lundo if it worked for you, can you please upvote me / write that my solution solved your issue? That's how we get points ;)

Comment: @Lundo I dont want to bother you, but please mark this answer as correct :) thank you!

Comment: I clicked the help check. I tried the up arrow but my rating isn't high enough to vote! Thanks for your answer.